# Long delay before AsyncTask doInBackground() starts

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, motorola-emdk

I have an Android app where when I switch from `Activity` A back to Main `Activity`, then to B, then press button the code calls an `AsyncTask`.

`OnPreExecute()` is called right away but it takes about a minute before `doInBackground()` is called.

I use `execute()` to start the task. Using `executeOnExecutor()` has no effect.

Why is there a delay?

I have checked and do not have any other `AsyncTasks` running.

I am running API 19 KitKat. No choice since it must run on TC-70 using EMDK.

Any ideas on where to start looking?

```
public class BarcodeHandler
    implements EMDKListener, DataListener, StatusListener, ScannerConnectionListener {

    @Override
    public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {
        String dataString = "test";

        new AsyncDataUpdate().execute(dataString);
    }

    ...
}
```

```
private class AsyncDataUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Log.d("delayTest", "DataUpdate PreExecute()");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d("delayTest", "DataUpdate doInBackground");
        return params[0];
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.d("delayTest", "DataUpdate onPostExecute");
        if (result != null) {
            if (dataListener != null)
                dataListener.barCodeListener(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you implement `AsyncTask`? Add some code of Activity and AsyncTask as well

Comment: can you share the activity and xml files?

Comment: are you sure there aren't other AsyncTask running?

Comment: Double check that no other component in your app (network libs, image loader libs, etc.) are using `AsyncTask`.  Also check the CPU usage.  The `AsyncTask` thread(s) should be ready to go, but by default will run serially.  If you called `executeOnExecutor` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` then you should not get blocked on other `AsyncTask`s which are running (unless they have exhausted the pool.)  If the CPU usage is high, it could be preventing any bg thread from getting context.

Comment: It seems harder to reproduce the problem when I build on my home machine.  Problem occurs more frequently when app is built at work.

Comment: Larry, CPU occasionally bumps up to 1.75 % for a 1/10 second.  So, no load while waiting.